# web2py how to import module at the same directory?

Tags: web2py

I have a file name `default.py` in controllers,and a file `getmsg.py` at the same directory,
but I can't import `getmsg` in `default.py`. Why not? How would I import it?

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\xampp\htdocs\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 212, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "F:/xampp/htdocs/web2py/applications/tools/controllers/default.py", line 11, in <module>
    import getmsg
  File "F:\xampp\htdocs\web2py\gluon\custom_import.py", line 81, in custom_importer
    raise ImportError, 'Cannot import module %s' % str(e)
ImportError: Cannot import module 'getmsg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web2py, controllers are not Python modules -- you don't import them. You can put modules in the application's /modules folder and import from there.

In theory, (assuming there is an `__init__.py` file in the /controllers folder) you can do:

```
import applications.myapp.controllers.getmsg
```

but that wouldn't be considered standard practice. In particular, controllers are not intended to be used as regular Python modules. They are executed in an environment in which much of the web2py API has already been defined, so if you import a controller as a module, its code may make reference to global objects that are not available, which will generate exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
from getmsg import Classname, methodname
```